# Work done by friction in a vertical circle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, friction

I have been unable to find any sources online on how to do such calculations, so I am trying my luck here.

In this scenario, an object (in this case a rollercoaster) moves on a track in the form of a vertical circle. It stays in contact with the track throughout the entire loop. I am trying to find the sum of the work done by friction in the first half of the loop, so that I can then use that in a conservation of energy equation to find other values.

Can I find the work done by friction in this way?
The speed used in the friction formula also changes along the loop. Do I have to integrate that first? If I leave it, will it be the same $v$ as in the $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ in the conservation of energy formula?
[image: screenshot]

If anyone can help or share any useful resources, it will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

Your equations are correct, but they may not be terribly useful.  The problem is that your integral involves the velocity $v$ of the object as a function of $\theta$;  and without knowing this function, you can't actually perform the integral.  To find $v(\theta)$, you'd have to find the energy lost by the object as an arbitrary function of $\theta$;  which would involve doing the integral with an arbitrary upper limit $\theta$ (instead of 180°);  which leads to a sort of infinite regress that's hard to get out of.

Instead, it's better to view this as a *differential* equation (instead of an *integral* equation, which is effectively how you've couched it).  The rate of change of the tangential velocity of an object moving in a circle is given by
$$
F_\text{tan} = m a_\text{tan} = m R \ddot{\theta}
$$
where $F_\text{tan}$ is the net force in the tangential direction (from gravity & friction, in your case); $m$ is the mass of the object;  $R$ is the radius of the circle; and $\ddot{\theta} = \frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2}$ is the angular acceleration of the object.

If you write all of this out you'll get a differential equation of the form
$$
\ddot{\theta} = \text{something involving $\theta$, $\dot{\theta}$, and various parameters}
$$
which can in principle be solved.  You will probably not be able to find a closed-form solution for this, but you could use numerical techniques to solve the problem for particular values of the initial velocity, $g$, $R$, and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem is little harder than it looks. One thing I want to do is get rid of degrees, $s$, and work only with on coordinate, and build it up step by step:

First: I am going to work entirely in (offset) polar coordinates, so that, at $\theta=0$, the total energy is the kinetic energy (and zero potential energy):

$$ E_0 = T_0 + U_0 = \frac 1 2 mr^2\omega_0^2$$

with:

$$ \omega_0 = \big(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\big)_{\theta=0} $$

As $\theta$ increases, there is a potential energy and a friction term:

$$ E_{\theta} = T_{\theta} + U_{\theta} + W_{\theta} $$
$$ E_{\theta} =  \frac 1 2 mr^2\omega^2 + mgr(1-\cos\theta) + W_{\theta} $$

Now the hard part, $W(\theta)$:

Copying your input (it looks right to me):

$$ F(\theta) = \mu m\big(r\dot\theta^2 + g\cos\theta\big)$$

so

$$ \int_0^{\theta} rFd\theta' $$
$$ W(\theta) =   \int_0^{\theta} \mu mr\big(r\dot\theta'^2 + g\cos\theta'\big)d\theta'$$

So the final equation is:

$$ \frac 1 2 mr^2\omega_0^2 =
\frac 1 2 mr^2\dot\theta^2 + mgr(1-\cos\theta) +
 \int_0^{\theta} \mu mr\big(r\dot\theta'^2 + g\cos\theta'\big)
d\theta'
$$

And that looks hard to solve.

Comment: It is hard to solve this in this form because the dissipation makes the Energy-first argument extremely difficult. It is slightly less disastrous to solve if you start with the torque equation, i.e. angular accelerations, and integrate from there.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent: Note that this torque equation can be recovered from this integral equation. Take the derivative of both sides with respect to $\theta$, apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to the integral term, and use some chain rule trickery to write $$\frac{d(\dot{\theta}^2)}{d\theta} = \frac{d(\dot{\theta}^2)}{dt} \frac{dt}{d\theta} = (2 \dot{\theta} \ddot{\theta}) \left( \frac{1}{\dot{\theta}} \right) =  2 \ddot{\theta}.$$ When the dust settles you'll end up with an equation that's equivalent to the torque equation.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert of course; both forms are correct, and the trajectory is unique, so they must end up agreeing. But the difficulty of solving is a totally different matter, not least because we are so much more capable of solving differential equations (by guessing) than solving integral equations, let alone diffeo-integral equations.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Ah, yes, I was considering taking the derivative...but didn't implement it. I think the point of my "answer" was to clarify the parts of the problem, which were a little jumbled in the initial question. Someone should do that and pot an actual solution.

Answer (score 1):

The work that done by friction force $~F_\mu~$ is

$$W=\int F_\mu\,ds=\int_0^\pi F_\mu\,r\,d\theta\tag 1 $$

with

$$F_\mu=\mu\,N=\mu\,m\,(r\,\dot\theta^2+g\cos(\theta))$$

how you obtain $~\dot\theta^2=\dot\theta^2(\theta)~$

with the energy

$$E=\frac m2\,v^2-m\,g\,r\,\cos(\theta)+F_\mu\,\theta\quad,v=r\,\dot \theta^2\\
E_0=E(\theta=0~,\dot\theta=0)=-m\,g\,r$$

and the conservation of the energy $~E=E_0~$ you obtain

$$\dot\theta^2=-2\,{\frac {g \left( \mu\,\theta\,\cos \left( \theta \right) +r-r\cos
 \left( \theta \right)  \right) }{r \left( 2\,\mu\,\theta + r \right) }}
$$

from here equation (1)

$$W=\int_0^\pi\,f(\theta)\,d\theta$$